# How to check if a place in array is empty

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check if in test array position is empty,
I have this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] test = new String[3];
test=in.nextLine().split(" ");
    if(test[0].equalsIgnoreCase("asd")&&test[1].equals("")){
        System.out.println("Enter");
    }
```

But it says that test[1] is out of range in this array.

Comment: what's the input you are entering?

Answer (score 2):

You should not declare your array on one line, only to throw that reference away and get a new array on the next line. Step one, change

```
String[] test = new String[3];
test=in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

to

```
// \\s+ instead of " " consumes extra whitespaces
String[] test = in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

which is equivalent, but doesn't throw away an extra array. Next, you need to check that your `split` actually produced the values you expected. And you can use `String.isEmpty()`. Like,

```
String[] test = "asd  b".split(" ");
if (test.length > 1 && test[0].equalsIgnoreCase("asd") && test[1].isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Enter");
}
```

Which outputs

```
Enter
```

Comment: I agree with this answer but the isEmpty() check seems pointless, can you ever get an empty item when splitting a string on " "?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes. `Arrays.stream("a  b  c".split(" ")).mapToInt(String::length).forEach(System.out::println);` And because that is hard to *read* it is a space space b space space c. Note that you would get a different result with `\\s+` as the split argument.

Comment: But that gives me  1 1 1 as the result, so none is empty

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `"a  b  c"` (letter a followed by two spaces then b then two spaces then c). I get 1 0 1 0 1. So two are empty. And code in comments is always terrible. I have edited the question to provide a working example that meets the criteria.

Comment: Thanks, that extra space somehow disappeared in your comment but when I added them back again I got the same result as you